# Rebus Azure Pub Sub pattern

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

I'm exploring the Rebus library. I implemented the Pub/Sub successfully in Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Worker project with `FileSystem` transport. But I'm struggling to make it work with `AzureServiceBus`. I have below configuration in Program.cs:

```
IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
            services.AddLogging();

            services.AddRebus(
                (config, provider) => {
                    config
                        .Logging(l => l.Console())
                        .Routing(r => r.TypeBased().MapAssemblyOf<CreateNewReportMessage>(busConfig.MainQueue))
                        //.Transport(x => x.UseFileSystem(busConfig.FileSystemTransportBaseDirectory, busConfig.MainQueue))
                        //.Subscriptions(x => x.UseJsonFile(Path.Combine(busConfig.FileSystemTransportBaseDirectory, "rebus_subscriptions.json")))
                        .Transport(x => x.UseAzureServiceBus(busConfig.AzureSBConnectionString, busConfig.MainQueue).AutomaticallyRenewPeekLock());
                    return config;
                },
                onCreated: async bus => {
                    await bus.Subscribe<CreateNewReportMessage>();
                }
            );
            services.AutoRegisterHandlersFromAssemblyOf<Program>();
        })
        .Build();

    await host.RunAsync();
```

I'm getting below 400 Bad request error. The app is published as Azure WebJob.

```
INFO] [DBG] Rebus.AzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusTransport (Thread #1): Registering subscription for topic "MyServiceBus/MyServiceBus.Messages.CreateNewReportMessage"
INFO]       Successfully created bus instance RebusBus Rebus 1 (isDefaultBus: True)
INFO]       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
INFO] fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[9]
INFO]       BackgroundService failed
INFO]        ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: The specified HTTP verb (GET) is not valid. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions. . TrackingId:1808
INFO]       Status: 400 (Bad Request)
INFO]          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
INFO]          at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.HttpRequestAndResponse.ThrowIfRequestFailedAsync(Request request, Response response)
INFO]          at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.HttpRequestAndResponse.SendHttpRequestAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
INFO]          at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.HttpRequestAndResponse.GetEntityAsync(String entityPath, String query, Boolean enrich, CancellationToken can
INFO]          at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration.ServiceBusAdministrationClient.TopicExistsAsync(String name, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
INFO]          at Rebus.AzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusTransport.EnsureTopicExists(String normalizedTopic)
INFO]          at Rebus.AzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusTransport.<>c__DisplayClass25_0.<<RegisterSubscriber>b__0>d.MoveNext()
INFO]       --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
INFO]          at Rebus.Internals.ExceptionIgnorant.Execute(Func`1 function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
INFO]          at Rebus.Internals.ExceptionIgnorant.Execute(Func`1 function, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
INFO]          at Rebus.AzureServiceBus.AzureServiceBusTransport.RegisterSubscriber(String topic, String subscriberAddress)
INFO]          at Rebus.Bus.RebusBus.InnerSubscribe(String topic)
```

Comment: This is most likely because the connection string you're using lacks the _Manage privilege.  You'll need to provide that, so Rebus can help you initialize queues with the correct settings, create topics, and manage subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did start to wonder about that. I'll get in touch with infra team and investigate.

Comment: Update: The connection string already have Manage level permissions. :(

Comment: Has the Endpoint part of the connection string been changed somehow?

Comment: Interestingly `bus.Advanced.Topics.Subscribe(typeof(CreateNewReportMessage).FullName)` is able to create topic on AzureSB but `bus.Subscribe<CreateNewReportMessage>()` fails with 400 (Bad Request).

Comment: That does not make any sense.... UNLESS `typeof(CreateNewReportMessage).        typeof(string).GetSimpleAssemblyQualifiedName()` happens to return a string that is too long!  Could you maybe check the length of the string returned from that extension method when called on your even type?

Comment: Do you mean the length of `typeof(CreateNewReportMessage).GetSimpleAssemblyQualifiedName()`, that is only 60 characters long?
Just another info - the queues are getting created properly.

Comment: I mean check the length of the string returned from `typeof(CreateNewReportMessage).GetSimpleAssemblyQualifiedName()` – it's the "short, assembly-qualified name" of the type, i.e. it includes the name of the assembly and the full namespace in addition to the class name, which COULD end up being too long for ASB, and thus lead to the cheap and silly BadRequest response

Comment: the string length is just 58 characters "MyServiceBus.Messages.CreateNewReportMessage, MyServiceBus"

Comment: Looking through AzureServiceBusTransport code, topic returned by [_nameFormatter.FormatTopicName(topic)](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/blob/master/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/AzureServiceBus/AzureServiceBusTransport.cs#L151) is "MyServiceBus/MyServiceBus.Messages.CreateNewReportMessage" containing '/' which is not accepted topic name in [ASB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/servicebus/azure-service-bus-azure-resource-manager-and-this-character). 400 bad request was because of that. One work around is to use `.UseLegacyNaming()`.

Comment: The '/' is indeed accepted both in queue and in topic names. In some tools (e.g. [ServiceBusExplorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer)) it will display queues and topics as if it was a directory structure when your queues/topics have '/' in them

Comment: Yes apologies my bad, it mentions on Azure new topic info too `Topic names can contain letters, numbers, periods (.), hyphens (-), underscores (_), and slashes (/), up to 260 characters. Topic names are also case-insensitive.`